# Computer restarts when booting from HD or USB

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb, desktop-computer

(I didn't add/remove any hardware)

Yesterday my ASUS Desktop PC couldn't manage to boot into Windows 7.
I tried to boot from an Installation USB too, with the same unsuccessful result.

I can use the BIOS, but then when I select the boot device, after a few seconds, at first it seems like it's booting but then the monitor goes black and the computer restarts.

Any clue what could cause this?

Comment: Did you try to boot into stand-alone Microsoft Memory Test? Did you try any other stand-alone bootable OS as Knoppix or Hiren's boot CD? http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually occurs with HDD when the SATA controller mode has changed from the native AHCI mode to the compatibility IDE mode, or vice-versa. If your HDD was formatted under one mode and Windows is installed in that mode, changing the controller configuration in BIOS to another mode will result in infinite loop of reboot cycles. For some strange reason any Windows recovery cannot find the issue and fix it. Try different modes in BIOS, it might fix the problem.